Transform text in GeoNodes using global orientation?
I want to transform and alter (live) text (not converted to a mesh) using global orientation.
The problem is that text is created facing the Z axis (back row of image) and geometry node transforms on the text are done using its local axis (center row of image) and it isn't possible to reset the local axis when text is live.
What I want to be able to do is to manually orient the text so the top of the letters are aligned with the Z axis (ie. rotate 90 along X) and then be able to apply geometry node transforms using the global axis (front row of image).


Can we have a use-case, so we can see what's unacceptable about rotating the 'Live' text inside  GN, (leaving object axes aligned to World)?

Why don't you use the 'String Curve' instead of a text object?

My specific question as I asked it was answered on Blender Artists so I am marking this solved, but it doesn't specifically solve my actual problem (which admittedly, I was not clear about).

